# How to change filetype association in the registry?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, file-extension

first time posting in StackOverflow. :D
I need my software to add a couple of things in the registry.

My program will use

> `Process.Start(@"blblabla.smc");`

to launch a file, but the problem is that most likely the user will not have a program set as default application for the particular file extension.

**How can I add file associations to the WindowsRegistry?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In addition to the answers already provided, you can accomplish this by calling the command line programs "ASSOC" and "FTYPE".  FTYPE associates a file type with a program.  ASSOC associates a file extension with the file type specified through FTYPE.  For example:

```
FTYPE SMCFile="C:\some_path\SMCProgram.exe" -some_option %1 %*
ASSOC .smc=SMCFile
```

This will make the necessary entries in the registry.  For more information, type `ASSOC /?` or `FTYPE /?` at the command prompt.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class in [`Microsoft.Win32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.aspx).

Specifically, you want the [`ClassesRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.classesroot.aspx) property of `Registry` to access the [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724475(VS.85).aspx) key (cf. [Understanding MS Windows File Associations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749986.aspx) and [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT: Core Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739822(WS.10).aspx)).

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
Registry
    .ClassesRoot
    .CreateSubKey(".smc")
    .SetValue("", "SMC", RegistryValueKind.String);
Registry
    .ClassesRoot
    .CreateSubKey("SMC\shell\open\command")
    .SetValue("", "SMCProcessor \"%1\"", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Replace `"SMCProcessor \"%1\""` with the command-line path and argument specification for the program that you wish to associate with files with extension `.smc`.

But, instead of messing with the registry, why not just say

```
Process.Start("SMCProcessor blblabla.smc");
```

Comment: I have this code:

'Process EmulatorProcess;

EmulatorProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Documents and Settings\serg\Desktop\Emubox v0.01\SuperNintendo\Roms\Super Mario RPG (U).smc");            
            EmulatorProcess.WaitForInputIdle();'

I used a hardcoded path just to test things out. How could I apply your last line of code to my needs? Thanks! :D

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13535039/1497596): *"The `RegistryKey` class implements `IDisposable` and so you should wrap your keys in a `using` statement."* Or, alternatively, you should call [Close or Dispose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37059244/1497596) on the `RegistryKey` when you are done with it. This means that including `CreateSubKey` in a method chain as shown in this example is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Using Python:

```
EXT, EXT_TYPE = ".xyz", "XYZ file"
EXE_PATH = r"path\to\my\exe"

# %L is the long (full path) version of path
extCmd = '"%s" "%%L" %%*' % EXE_PATH

# Using assoc and ftype easier than editing registry!
assert os.system('assoc %s=%s' % (EXT, EXT_TYPE))==0
assert os.system('ftype %s=%s' % (EXT_TYPE, extCmd))==0
```

Associating an icon with the extension type:

```
import _winreg

try:
    ext = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, EXT_TYPE)
    _winreg.SetValue(ext, "DefaultIcon", _winreg.REG_SZ, ICON_PATH)
    _winreg.CloseKey(ext)
except WindowsError:
    print "Error associating icon"
```

Register the extension as an executable type (i.e. PATHEXT):

```
try:
    key = r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'

    reg = _winreg.ConnectRegistry( None, _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE )

    # get current value
    ext = _winreg.OpenKey(reg, key)
    pathext = _winreg.QueryValueEx(ext, 'PATHEXT')[0]

    if not EXT in pathext:
        _winreg.CloseKey(ext)

        # modify the current value            
        ext = _winreg.OpenKey(reg, key, 0, _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        pathext += ';' + EXT
        _winreg.SetValueEx(ext, 'PATHEXT', 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, pathext)
        _winreg.CloseKey(ext)

    _winreg.CloseKey(reg)

except WindowsError:
    print "Error adding to PATHEXT"
```

Additionally, to get PATHEXT recognised without logging in again you can update the environment: (thanks to Enthought for this)

```
def refreshEnvironment():        
    HWND_BROADCAST      = 0xFFFF
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE    = 0x001A
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG    = 0x0002
    sParam              = "Environment"

    import win32gui
    res1, res2          = win32gui.SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, sParam, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on providing an installer for your application, simply use the file association feature available in whatever installer framework you choose to use - even the Visual Studio setup project knows how to do this.

To alter file type associations directly from your code, I believe you have to look into `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and find/create a key with the extension you want to bind to (ie ".pdf"). Within this key, the default value is a string containing a reference to another key within `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Go follow that pointer, expand/create the `shell` subkey and add/change your commands here. Look around this area with `regedit` to get the fealing of how it looks.

I have some C# code in a pet project of mine, which looks up the binding for PDF files and adds an extra option to their context menus. Feel free to [have a look](http://code.google.com/p/pdfbinder/source/browse/trunk/src/ShellInstaller.cs).