# How can I associate files using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've made a program using C# and I want know how to associate file which output  to open by using this program.
this program made files with an extension .fct I want this files with that extension open in my program when it double clicked

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically create a file association that works in XP, Vista and Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807742/how-to-programmatically-create-a-file-association-that-works-in-xp-vista-and-wi)

Comment: @SteveB: Yep, that works for your computer.  Not so much for a customer's.

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application

Comment: This is definitely a "real question".  OP, follow M4N's link (he voted for dup)

Comment: @EdS.: I was a bit ironic... the question did not give details, so I answer with an undetailled answer

Comment: @SteveB: Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into this: http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/

Comment: @M4N I modify my question to understand and answer this is problem and  there are solve if you can answer this question

Comment: @usr I modify my question to understand and answer this is problem and there are solve if you can answer this question