# Create a file extension for theme builder

Tags: c#, winforms, file-extension

I am making a theme builder for iPhone/iPod touch. Usually the folders are suffixed with .theme. For my application, could I possible make an file extension, .iTheme, and associate my application with the .iTheme extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. [This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/associate-file-extension-with-vcl-forms-application) first answer lists the steps for doing so. It's for Delphi instead of C#, but the steps are the same either way.

Comment: How do I do this in Visual Studio 2008-2010.

Comment: There are dozens of posts here on using the Windows registry from C#. A quick search on "Registry C#" turned up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082889/how-to-change-filetype-association-in-the-registry - the second answer to that shows you the exact .NET classes and sample use for adding a file association to the registry.