# Injecting a file type association in java into a Windows or Mac Environmets

Tags: java

How're we supposed to inject a file type association in java into a Windows or Mac environments?  For instance registering .vlan file type to our java application!  This would of course need to happen when the application is launching for the first time!

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can understand, for Windows, it involves Windows registry; for Mac, plist [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082889/how-to-change-filetype-association-in-the-registry/1082925#1082925](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082889/how-to-change-filetype-association-in-the-registry/1082925#1082925)

Comment: Please fix that sticky '?' key and tone down the exclamatory nature of your writing (I.E. use '!' sparingly).

Answer (score 1):

- Deploy the application using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).
- Declare a file type association in the JNLP file.

Part of the [demo. of the `FileContents` API](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) shows how to do the latter.

> .. the launch file prompts the user to associate file extension `.zzz` (simply a file type unlikely to clash with existing file associations) of content type `text/sleepytime`. ..

This should work on Windows, OS X **&** *nix.