# Read registry key in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I'm reading the value of a registry key:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = *someLongPathHere*;
```

and displaying the value to a label:

```
string a = (string)key.GetValue("");//a default value
label1.Text = a;
```

It displays:

```
{F241C880-6982-4CE5-8CF7-7085BA96DA5A}
```

which is mostly correct, except for the first underscore, which exists in the original value:

```
{_F241C880-6982-4CE5-8CF7-7085BA96DA5A}
```

Why does it happen? i.e the missing underscore?

Also, after reading the key, do I have to close the key or anything? How can I do it?

Comment: oh right, sorry I forgot to add them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough to test whether or not there is a systematic problem with string values containing underscores. You can simply create such a value in the registry editor and then read it into your C# program with `GetValue()`. When you do so you'll discover that the C# registry code doesn't lose underscores. So, there must be some other explanation for your problem.

My best guess is that your label component does not display the underscore. I'm not very familiar with the C# UI frameworks but that seems plausible. Try looking at the value of `a` under the debugger rather than in a label caption on your UI.

The other thing that comes to mind is that you have registry redirection because you have an x86 process running on x64, and your key is under a redirected key, HKLM\Software, for example. Perhaps if you look under the Wow6432Node you will see the underscore discrepancy.

As for managing the life of the key, the key is backed by an unmanged resource. Namely a Windows `HKEY`. The `RegistryKey` class implements `IDisposable` and so you should wrap your keys in a `using` statement.

Comment: the value of `a` is also without the underscore

Comment: When I put `{_F241C880-6982-4CE5-8CF7-7085BA96DA5A}` into a WPF label, the underscore is not visible. Which framework are you using.

Comment: I tried `label1.Text = "{_F241C880-6982-4CE5-8CF7-7085BA96DA5A}";` and it worked, so I think that's not the prob. Probably because of the `string` cast?

Comment: No it's not the string cast. The registry reading code is fine and the conclusion we draw is that the value you are reading does not have an underscore.

Comment: you're right, I tried adding `12345` to the end of the actual value but the result `a` is still the same. How can I find the Wow6432 ?

Comment: oh I found it. You're absolutely right, no underscore there. Thanks!