# Will disposing a RegistryKey also close it?

Tags: c#, registry

As the title says.

Also, the other way around; will closing a RegistryKey dispose it?

I've looked around in all documentation I could find and nothing of this is mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will call the `Dispose()` method inside of `Close()`, meaning **YES** it will be "`disposed`" and other way around `Dispose()` will `Close()` `key`. System registry keys are never `closed`. Only `keys` that are being `closed` - `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`.

.NET source for `Close` method:

```
/**
 * Closes this key, flushes it to disk if the contents have been modified.
 */
public void Close() {
    Dispose(true);
}
```

[.NET source line 220](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs,2e18a8a6ac71839b,references)

.NET source for `Dispose` method:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
private void Dispose(bool disposing) {
      if (hkey != null) {
           if (!IsSystemKey()) {
              try {
                  hkey.Dispose();
                }
                catch (IOException){
                    // we don't really care if the handle is invalid at this point
                }
                finally
                {
                    hkey = null;
                }
            }
            else if (disposing && IsPerfDataKey()) {
            SafeRegistryHandle.RegCloseKey(RegistryKey.HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA);
            }  
      }
}
```

[.NET source line 227](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs,2e18a8a6ac71839b,references)