# Integrate Windows 8 program with windows search

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to know if it is possible to have data from my Windows 8 program be able to show up in windows search. For instance, the user could search for "myprogramdata1" in windows and then an item would show up that when clicked would open up my program and I'd be able know that "myprogramdata1" was selected.

EDIT:

I know that it is possible for windows 10. For the program DisplayFusion, if I search settings, there is a result for DisplayFusion settings that can be clicked on and will bring me to the settings page for the program. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1082889/479512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of see if you say the command that you typed in using cortana and if it opens settings. If yes, You can absolutely do it.

I did it for one of my app too( Well this was not my intention but it works )

[UWP Samples-CortanaVoiceCommand](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand)

The key here is once Voice Commands are installed, you can type the text in cortana search (instead of actual voice command) and it works the same. You can still use patterns of voice commands and still type in Cortana search and open your app.

Comment: That could work. What I would really like is the search functionality that Windows 8.0 had but I think Microsoft scrapped it. Your examples are with UWP, but my application is a Windows 8.1 app. Would this be implementable in a 8.1 app?

Comment: Absolutely. But its done little differently than what it is for UWP. Check this link. https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/09/23/cortana-integration-and-speech-recognition-new-code-samples/ On a Side Note, I personally thought Integrating Cortana search in 8.1 was little tiresome that in 10. but you get the same result.

Comment: Great, this could definitely be the way I go then. I am testing your project out and when I go to the search and type, "Adventure Works, show trip to London" it only wants to search the web.

Comment: I know this issue. Reason Being Voice Commands are not installed during first run. Itried running the app multiple times and then was able to get  things going. To verify if the app installed Voice Commands, Click on cortana, Go to help and if you scroll all the way to bottom, you should see the command examples there. If you see them there then they are installed and it should work.

Comment: Also if this works, Mark this as an accepted answer.

Comment: Your examples show up, but still typing them in is unrecognized. In fact, most of the built in Cortana Examples do not work if I type them in.