# Editing the Windows registry doesn't impact the default "open" action when double-clicking files

Tags: c#, registry, associations

I've written a simple launch-handling application for Windows 10 which I want to set as the default application for several file types.

Through reading this question: ([How to change filetype association in the registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082889/how-to-change-filetype-association-in-the-registry)) I discovered that you can very simply record a new application in the Windows registry and then register a new file type that lists the new application as the default application. I used the file type ".rains" and the application name "Clouds" to test this as follows:

```
FTYPE Clouds="C:\Users\bob\source\repos\TL\TL\bin\Release\TL.exe" "%1"
ASSOC .rains=Clouds
```

Double-clicking on a file of type ".rains" launched my application perfectly.

I hoped that the general logic might be the same for overwriting existing file associations, i.e. I would be able to replace the "(Default)" entry for any given file type in the registry with "Clouds". However, when editing existing file type records in the Windows registry, I was unable to produce the same result as I achieved with the ".rains" file type.

I also noticed that when changing the default app for a file type by right-clicking on the file, Open With->Choose Another app, and checking the "Always use this app to open *** files", the behaviour for opening the file is changed (as expected) but the registry entry for the file type does not change. I've checked the HKLM, HKCU, and HKCR but the change doesn't seem to be reflected in any of these. The file type entry points to the same application name, and the executable path under the application name remains the same as well.

This leads me to conclude that the registry (or at least the part of the registry that I'm looking at) is not the only place Windows stores the default preferences that I want to edit.

For what it's worth, I also attempted to configure the file associations using DISM and the OEM default application XML sheet (as per https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsinternals/2017/10/25/windows-10-how-to-configure-file-associations-for-it-pros/) without any success.

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me? Is there another registry of sorts I'm meant to be editing?
Or is it possibly the impact of some IT policy implemented by my workplace?

Note - I'm keen to add a segment to my application which allows programmatic configuration of these defaults. Otherwise the GUI route would work fine.

Many thanks.

Comment: The change is done in the **UserChoce** key. For example, if I change for .a  extension : _HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.a\UserChoice_. (_ProgId_ and _Hash_) By code,  I change it  like Explorer, with the **IApplicationAssociationRegistrationInternal** interface

Comment: Thanks @Castorix, this is great. I haven't had much time to play around with this yet but I can see the application referenced there as expected. Out of interest - what documentation did I miss that points to this key? In the Microsoft docs I think I ended up wandering down a rabbit hole about file associations and registration relating to the shell... Even Googling the interface that you've mentioned returns suprisingly few results.

Comment: I think MS doesn't want anymore that random apps can change associations easily without user intervention...